# How to print std::list elements using DBX

Tags: c++, list, printing, std, dbx

I have  a a list like:

```
std::list<X *>::iterator     c;
for ( c = its_RcpList.begin(); c != its_RcpList.end(); c++ )
{
        if ( ID == (*c)->ID() ) ...

       ...
    }
```

How can I print the elements of a std::list in the dbx ? Specifically I want to print the ID values stored in the RcpList.

X is ;

```
class X
{
...
std::string         &ID() { return its_ID; }
std::string             its_ID;
...
};

class Y {
std::list<X *>          its_RcpList;
..
};
```

Comment: So you mean using `std::cout`?

Comment: No in the dbx. Got the answer : p *(its_RcpList->_Head->_Next->_Value)